# Efficient way to solve matrix equation in Python

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix

Right now I am using the `numpy.linalg.solve` to solve my matrix, but the fact that I am using it to solve a 5000*17956 matrix makes it really time consuming. It runs really slow and It have taken me more than an hour to solve. The running time for this is probably O(n^3) for solving matrix equation but I never thought it would be that slow. Is there any way to solve it faster in Python?

My code is something like that, to solve a for the equation `BT * UT = BT*B a`, where `m` is the number of test cases (in my case over 5000), `B` is a data matrix `m*17956`, and `u` is `1*m`.

```
C = 0.005                        # hyperparameter term for regulization
I = np.identity(17956)          # 17956*17956 identity matrix
rhs = np.dot(B.T, U.T)          # (17956*m) * (m*1)     = 17956*1
lhs = np.dot(B.T, B)+C*I        # (17956*m) * (m*17956) = 17956*17956
a = np.linalg.solve(lhs, rhs)   # B.T u = B.T B a, solve for a (17956*1)
```

Comment: I am not a matrix expert, but why can you not multiply each side by B.T^-1 to remove the B.T term?

Comment: Finding the inverse of a matrix is computationally inefficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your matrix is sparse, the `scipy.sparse.linalg` module will be useful. [Here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.linalg.html) is the documentation for the whole module, and [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve) is the documentation for `spsolve`.

Answer (score 2):

**Update (2 July 2018):** The updated question asks about the impact of a regularization term and the type of data in the matrices. In general, this can make a large impact in terms of the datatypes a particular CPU is most optimized for (as a rough rule of thumb, AMD is better with vectorized integer math and Intel is better with vectorized floating point math when all other things are held equal), and the presence of a large number of zero values can allow for the use of sparse matrix libraries. In this particular case though, the changes on the main diagonal (well under 1% of all the values in consideration) will have a negligible impact in terms of runtime.

TLDR;

- An hour is reasonable (a cubic regression suggests that this would take around 83 minutes on my machine -- a low-end chromebook).
- The pre-processing to generate `lhs` and `rhs` account for almost none of that time.
- You won't be able to solve **that exact problem** much faster than with `numpy.linalg.solve`.
- If `m` is small as you suggest and if `B` is invertible, you can instead solve the equation `U.T=Ba` in a minute or less.
- If this is part of a larger problem, this costly intermediate step might be able to  be simplified away from a mathematical framework.
- Performance bottlenecks really should be addressed with profiling to figure out which step is causing the issues.
- Since this comes from real-world data, you might be able to get away with fewer features (either directly or through a reduction step like PCA, NMF, or LLE), depending on the end goal.
- As mentioned in another answer, if the matrix is sufficiently sparse you can get away with sparse linear algebra routines to great effect (many natural language processing data sources are like this).
- Since the output is a 1D vector, I would use `np.dot(U, B).T` instead of `np.dot(B.T, U.T)`. Transposes are neat that way. This avoids doing the transpose on a big matrix like `B`, though since you have a cubic operation as the dominant step this doesn't matter much for your problem.
- Depending on whether you need the original data anymore and if the matrices involved have any other special properties, you **might** be able to fiddle with the parameters in `scipy.linalg.solve` instead for a gain.
- I've had mixed success replacing large matrix equations with block matrix equations falling back on numpy routines. That approach typically saves 5-20% over numpy approaches and takes 1% or so off scipy approaches on my system. I haven't fully explored the reason for the discrepancy.

Comment: However it has been a few hours now and it is still computing.

Comment: @JamesLiu That's a little strange.  What are the circumstances? CPU specs? RAM specs? CPU usage? RAM usage? OS? Python version? etc...? The code is fine. We don't have a lot else to go on for a diagnosis.

Comment: I am using python 3.7 64-bit, i think it is the latest version. I am using a 7700hq with 2.8 Ghz which I think is definitely more than enough for this computation. Does that have something to do with what values goes into B and U? My u contains only -1 and 1 and my U contains either 0 or 1 value. To get ride of singularity that cannot provide the equation a unique solution I added a penalized term CI to BT*U , where c is some coefficient really small and I is the identity matrix. Could that have something to do with the computation complexity? I dont think this will matter

Comment: Is anything else running before or after this code? All else held equal, I ran just the code you have posted and am not having to wait several hours. My computer should be substantially slower than yours. It isn't fast per se since you're doing around 6-18 **terra** operations, but it isn't taking 3+ hours either.

Comment: I have tested the code before and including reading the input it only took less than a minute or so. This is really strange. I will rerunning the code to see how long it took for the rest.